# Регулярное выражение для формата 12K etc.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Всех в наставшим Новым годом, ура!

Теперь о грустном.
Делаю что-то типа "лайка", так вот после того как число лайков достигнет 12000, нужно как-то привести к такому виду 12К, с округлением, типа так: 12 050 = 12.1К; 12 005 = 12К. Все, что до 1000 цифрой.

Спасибо.

Comment: А причём тут регулярные выражения? И что вызывает затруднения: сравнение количества лайков с 1000 или деление количества лайков на 1000 с сохранением только одного знака после запятой?

Comment: не подумал...

Answer (score 1):

Нет времени объяснять:

```
<?php

class Formatter
{
    public function scaleNumber($number)
    {
        $base = 1000;
        $scale = 0;
        $scales = array('', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'P');
        $scaledNumber = $number;
        while (($scaledNumber / $base) > 1
            && $scale < sizeof($scales) - 1
        ) {
            $scaledNumber /= $base;
            $scale++;
        }
        if (!$scale) {
            return $number;
        }
        $formattedNumber = number_format($scaledNumber, 1, '.', '');
        return trim($formattedNumber, '0.') . $scales[$scale];
    }
}

$formatter = new Formatter;
$numbers = array(
    10,
    33333,
    54321 * 1000,
    76231 * 1000 * 1000,
    82345 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000, // HI THAR 64 BIT
    82345 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000,
);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $formatter->scaleNumber($number), PHP_EOL;
}
```